# IIS 7 consuming connections and not releasing them

Tags: sybase, connection-pooling

We have a asp.net website, hosted by IIS7. The website functions normally without any problem.

But after a while, like 1 or 2 months, the Sybase database which the website connects to will produce this error whenever accessed by any application : `Maximum number of connections already opened`

At first we didn't realize that it was the web site's application pool  that causes this, so we restart the database and everything is back to normal.

But then the 2nd time, the 3rd time ... and we came to aware that we just need to restart the application pool for those unreleased connection to be released.

I checked the source code, there was only one place has database-connect-code and it was a very simple code which connects to the db, get the results then close it :

```
con.open()
x = con.getdata()
con.close
```

Btw, after checking the application's log, there wasn't any error or exceptions so I'm pretty sure that the `con.close` is probably reached and executed.

So if we could rule out the possibility that there were unclosed connections in the source code, is there any other explanation for this ?

Comment: I would consider checking what happens if your getdata() call fails with an error, does that exit cleanly or if not leave the connection hanging. You should not need to re-start the Sybase database to fix the application pool  but rather bouncing the app pool should clean that up usually. Also check what your max app pool size is vs the 'number of user connections' setting in Sybase to ensure your pool isn't bigger than the instance maximum. I would say you need to do some debugging and ensure that the close method is actually being called though.

Comment: @RichCampbell thanks, but as I mentioned above, there wasn't any error found in the log. While debugging, I check the connection state of the connection by every steps, and every thing is perfectly normal. I'm pretty confident that in the source code, the connection will always be closed ( we also put con.close in the catch )